# I want to override js function on shipping method section

Tags: magento-1.9, prototype-js

I want to override js function on shipping method section :
i checked on inspect Element below is the function is calling on click on continue 
  button Can you please help me to find out where i can get that function

```
onclick="shippingMethod.save()




<checkout_onepage_index>
    <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/custom.js</name></action>
        </reference>
        </checkout_onepage_index>
```

path : skin\frontend\package\theme\js\custom.js

```
// shipping method
var ShippingMethod = Class.create();
ShippingMethod.prototype = {
    initialize: function(form, saveUrl){
        this.form = form;
        if ($(this.form)) {
            $(this.form).observe('submit', function(event){this.save();Event.stop(event);}.bind(this));
        }
        this.saveUrl = saveUrl;
        this.validator = new Validation(this.form);
        this.onSave = this.nextStep.bindAsEventListener(this);
        this.onComplete = this.resetLoadWaiting.bindAsEventListener(this);
    },

    validate: function() {
        var methods = document.getElementsByName('shipping_method');
        if (methods.length==0) {
            alert(Translator.translate('Your order cannot be completed at this time as there is no shipping methods available for it. Please make necessary changes in your shipping address.').stripTags());
            return false;
        }

        if(!this.validator.validate()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (var i=0; i<methods.length; i++) {
            if (methods[i].checked) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        alert(Translator.translate('Please specify shipping method.').stripTags());
        return false;
    },

    save: function(){
alert('tttttttttttttttttttt');
        if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;
        if (this.validate()) {
            checkout.setLoadWaiting('shipping-method');
            var request = new Ajax.Request(
                this.saveUrl,
                {
                    method:'post',
                    onComplete: this.onComplete,
                    onSuccess: this.onSave,
                    onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout),
                    parameters: Form.serialize(this.form)
                }
            );
        }
    },

    resetLoadWaiting: function(transport){
        checkout.setLoadWaiting(false);
    },

    nextStep: function(transport){
        if (transport && transport.responseText){
            try{
                response = eval('(' + transport.responseText + ')');
            }
            catch (e) {
                response = {};
            }
        }

        if (response.error) {
            alert(response.message);
            return false;
        }

        if (response.update_section) {
            $('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
        }

        payment.initWhatIsCvvListeners();

        if (response.goto_section) {
            checkout.gotoSection(response.goto_section, true);
            checkout.reloadProgressBlock();
            return;
        }

        if (response.payment_methods_html) {
            $('checkout-payment-method-load').update(response.payment_methods_html);
        }

        checkout.setShippingMethod();
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to find out the exact location & file name

Comment: The function is defined at **skin\frontend\base\default\js\opcheckout.js** around line 624. Here `shippingMethod` is class and `save()` is the function.

Comment: can you please paste the code here of what you are referring line no 624

Comment: I have added the code which you want to change in the answer below. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

shippingMethod is created in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml`

class ShippingMethid is in `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js`
somewhere at 591 line.

And this is how you can override JS methods:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13379034/how-to-override-product-js-file-in-magento

This also works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941257/overriding-extending-the-magento-core-javascript-files

Comment: can you please paste the code here of what you are referring line no 591

Comment: i followed the above steps but its not override the function in my custom .js

Comment: how you have done that?

Answer (score 1):

`skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/js/opcheckout.js  //shipping method`